# Overriding drawRect doesn't inhibit iOS UIKit drawing

Tags: objective-c, uikit

I'm a little confused on how overriding functions work in Objective-C regarding to overriding Framework functions.
For example: If I override the `drawRect`: function of an `UITextView`, the `UITextView` still does draw text and selection markers.

Can anyone explain me why this works? I would expect that overriding `drawRect` wouldn't call the super implementation of `UITextView`'s drawRect, otherwise I explicitly call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `drawRect` method is only responsible for drawing the view itself. If the view has some subviews, overriding `drawRect` won’t stop these from appearing. Maybe this is your case with the text view?

Comment: Stupid me, that could be the problem!